# How do I use a .NET core class library in a .NET core application?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Specifically on ubuntu, this doesn't appear to work.

For example, if I do this:

```
dotnet new sln -n HelloWorld
dotnet new classlib -n HelloLib
dotnet new console -n HelloApp
dotnet sln add ./HelloApp/HelloApp.csproj
dotnet sln add ./HelloLib/HelloLib.csproj
dotnet restore
dotnet build

cd HelloApp/
dotnet add reference ../HelloLib/HelloLib.csproj
```

And modify Program.cs to be:

```
using System;
using HelloLib;

namespace HelloApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new Class1();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then the application will *compile*, generating these artifacts:

```
HelloApp/bin$ du -a
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloApp.deps.json
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloApp.runtimeconfig.json
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloApp.pdb
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloLib.pdb
8   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloApp.dll
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
4   ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1/HelloLib.dll
36  ./Debug/netcoreapp1.1
40  ./Debug
44  .
```

...but executing the application fails:

```
$ dotnet HelloApp.dll 

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'HelloLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I remove the `using HelloLib` line, it works:

```
$ dotnet HelloApp.dll 
Hello World!
```

What's up with that?

I presume its got something to do with the confusing incompatibility in the project files:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework> <-- **THIS**
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

vs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework> <-- **And THIS**
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\HelloLib\HelloLib.csproj">
      <Project>{1607a379-5bae-423b-8efc-796a06556be0}</Project>
      <Name>HelloLib</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I assumed this was just a bug.

...but other people seem to use .NET core without too much trouble.

So, am I doing something wrong?

Or are the people 'using' .NET core just not using class libraries, because they don't work?

(edit: versions:

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

$ dpkg -l |grep dotnet
ii  dotnet-dev-1.0.3                                                 1.0.3-1                                      amd64        .NET Core SDK 1.0.3

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.10 \n \l
```

Comment: Is your dll exists from your working project directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you do

```
dotnet add reference ../HelloLib/HelloLib.csproj
```

You must do an additional

```
dotnet restore
```

so the references will be properly tracked by the project. If you follow your same steps but add a `dotnet restore` after the `dotnet add reference` step it works fine.

Any time you change or update your refrences you must call `dotnet restore` afterward or change your `dotnet build` statement to be `dotnet build /t:restore` so it will do the restore before the build for you.

Comment: oo... `dotnet build /t:restore` seems to be the magic sauce I was missing. thank you~